# Connecting few "if" conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 12 `<a>` tags and they are linked to image. What i want to do is to connect all of them in one `if` as a `.clicked == true`. For some reason it does not work so here i am with another question.

A sample of my `<a>` tag.

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="slider">
        </div>
        
        <div id="wypelniacz">
              <a href="javascript: text(1);"><img style="top: 22%; right: 60%;" alt="" src="greenapple.png" class="apl" id="apple1" onclick="imageSwap(1) ; this.onclick=null;"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function imageSwap(id)
        {           
            document.getElementById("apple" + id).src = "redapple.png";
        }
```

To make it easier to explain i have posted a picture of what am i doing.
When apple is not clicked it remains green, but when i click on it, it will change to red.
Then, when all 12apples are red the whole div copntent will be deleted and swapped for one image. How can i possibly do that? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Simplest option: Inside `imageSwap` add a check to see if all `src`'s have changed (Or add a class/attribute and check for that, checking `src` directly is a bit weird) and run your "swap things over" code if they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So add a class for attribute and check how many you have

```
function imageSwap(id) {
  var img = document.getElementById("apple" + id);
  img.src = "redapple.png";
  img.classList.add("selected");
  var count = document.querSelectorAll(".selected").length;
  console.log(count);
}
```

or just with html and css

```js
document.querySelector(".tree").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  const checked = document.querySelectorAll(".apple:checked").length;
  console.log(checked);
  console.log(evt.target.form.checkValidity());
});
```

```css
.apple {
  display: none;
}

.apple + label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100);
}

.apple:checked + label {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<form class="tree">
<input type="checkbox" class="apple" id="apple1" required><label for="apple1"></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple" id="apple2" required><label for="apple2"></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple" id="apple3" required><label for="apple3"></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple" id="apple4" required><label for="apple4"></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple" id="apple5" required><label for="apple5"></label>

<button>Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am too new into this to think of it by myself. I've researched for this all day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use event delegation, that is I attach a click event to '.container', and use 'event.target' to manipulate the target apple
2. toggle target apple class to switch background-color
3. check all apples, if there is no '.red', then switch to a new image(Here I just remove the '.red' class all)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ev => {
  const apples = [...document.querySelectorAll('.apple')]
  const container = document.querySelector('.container')
  container.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    if (ev.target.matches('.apple')) {
      ev.preventDefault()

      ev.target.classList.toggle('red')
      const apples = [...container.querySelectorAll('.apple')]
      if (apples.every(apple => apple.classList.contains('red'))) {
        apples.forEach(apple => apple.classList.remove('red'))
      }
    }
  })
}, false)
```

```css
  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .apple {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    background: green;
  }

  .green {
    background: green;
  }

  .red {
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" data-id="0" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="1" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="2" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="3" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="4" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="5" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="6" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="7" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="8" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="9" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="10" class="apple"></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="11" class="apple"></a>
  </div>
```